# PostgreSQL numeric type and anorm parser with Play! scala 2.3

Tags: postgresql, scala, playframework-2.3, anorm

I want to use the numeric type of Postgresql 9.3 but my parser :

```
private val Account403Parser: RowParser[Account403] = {
  get[Long]("id") ~
  get[Float]("amount") map {
  case id ~ amount =>
    Account403.apply(id, amount)
}
```

doesn't work since anorm can't convert from java.math.BigDecimal to Float.

Here is the error that I get :

`[RuntimeException: TypeDoesNotMatch(Cannot convert 9.5: class java.math.BigDecimal to Float for column ColumnName(account403.amount,Some(amount)))]`

How can I change my parser to make it convert from the java.math.BigDecimal type to the Float type?

Comment: More numeric conversions are available in master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [type-compatibility matrix in the documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/ScalaAnorm#Type-compatibility) you should use

`BigDecimal`, `Double` or `Long` to assign a `BigDecimal`.

Or you could cast to [`real`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html) (4-byte floating point number) on the Postgres side: `amount::real`, thereby *losing* some precision. Not sure about the syntax in scala.